# Preventation from form thread blockage from join of another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a method which writes some text on the Form and runs on a thread.

When i stop it by a button it will also write some texts on the box but in that time my main methot is waiting on the join method.

```
    private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A.stop_byuser(); //Some code with end with a log writing

        foreach(Thread t in threads)
        {
            if (t.IsAlive)
                t.Join();//Stops for finishing of thread
        }
    }
```

Thread is coming to my log writing code before finishing and it is using Form elements:

```
public void write_log(TextBox tb, String value)
        {
            if (tb.InvokeRequired) {
                tb.Invoke(write_log_delegate, tb, value + "\n");//At here code is waiting
            }
            else
                tb.Text += value + "\n";
        }
```

How can i eliminate this useless waiting.

Comment: `How can i eliminate this unfinite waiting loop` Where is this *infinite loop* ?

Comment: Replace `tb.Invoke()` with `tb.BeginInvoke()`, but that's just a stop-gap.

Comment: It works but slow. What is the raison behind this?

Comment: You're still calling Join() from the main thread. Carefully read the answer on the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: changing to more complex solution to avoid using Abort() as commented on below:

In your thread, you need a loop to check a reset event:

```
while (running)
{
/* Put thread code here */
if (stopEvent.WaitOne(500) || !running)
break;
}
```

Then use WaitHandle.WaitAll() to wait on all the threads to finish.

```
running = false;
foreach (var evt in stopEvents)
{
   evt.Set();
}

// Wait for all threads to finish
WaitHandle.WaitAll(stopEvents);
```

Comment: Always avoid Thread.Abort().

Comment: If I use abort it eliminates and also my finishing process and writes nothing.

Comment: I would use Abort() in a try/catch (ThreadAbortException) {} and just ignore the exception (for simplicity) but I edited my answer to a more elegant solution.

Comment: The WaitHandle is a lot better but calling it from the GUI thread is still very wrong.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Interested to hear your suggestions?

Comment: If you are waiting for something in a GUI event-handler thread, you are always doing wrong. Always.